# How to render background image for camera with Cycles

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, camera, compositing-nodes, image

I don't want to add it as a plane because then my scene lights affect the image and it's going to be hard to make it follow camera movements.

I saw on Youtube that if you use some nodes you can get the background image for camera to render but it didn't work, perhaps something has changed since then?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should work: make sure to check the "Transparent" Film Render option, and set the background image on camera to "Crop", for a perfect corrispondence with the compositing image.

[image]

Comment: It works on a dummy file but not on my main file, any idea what could be the problem?

Comment: Is the "Compositor" option checked in the rendering properties, post processing tab?

Comment: It wasn't, and now it seems to work. Also, to anyone else needing the same help it's not in the Render Properties, it's in the Output Properties

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround, in *Render Layers* node there is a small button on the bottom right that says "Render active scene", and that should work if <kbd>F12</kbd> doesn't.

[image]